# Show list of numbers 1-10 multiplied by user entered number

Tags: javascript, strings, ecmascript-6, iteration

- Objective of this program is to have the user enter 2 or 9 and output
  the respective numbers multiple by 2 10 times.
- Example if a user enters 2, browser will output the following:

  ```
  2 times 2 is:4
  3 times 2 is:6
  ⋮
  11 times 2 is:22
  ```
- I want like to know how can I simplify the underneath code? I have
  placed the computation of the user entered value multiple by 2, on 2
  separate" if else-if" statements. In case the user enters a wrong
  number and subsequently when he enters the correct value, the values
  wil be multipled by 2. See Loop A and Loop B comments to understand
  what I mean.

```js
let value = prompt("Enter Value between 2 or 9");

document.write(value);
document.write(`<br>`);

if (value == 2 || value == 9) {
//Loop A, when user enters 2 or 9, a list of its multiple by 2 is output to the user 10 
//times since I have already written the logic here how do I ensure it do not 
//write it again
 
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    value2 = value * 2;
    document.write(`${value} times 2 is:${value2}`);
    document.write(`<br>`);
    //by adding "value++" the user entered value will increment
    value++;
  }
} else if (value < 2 || value > 9) {
  for (i = 0;(value < 2 || value > 9); i++) {
    value = prompt("Enter Value between 2 or 9");

    if (value == 2 || value == 9) {
    //Loop B, I want the computation to go to loop A instead of me having to write 
    //the computation of user value x 2
  //How can i accompolise this
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        value2 = value * 2;
        document.write(`${value} times 2 is:${value2}`);
        document.write(`<br>`);
        //by adding "value++" the user entered value will increment
        value++;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript_multi_validation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please include a description of what the code does. Every one here want to "simplify code".

Comment: Hi, i've indicated on the top the objective of the program
"Objective of this program is to have the user enter 2 or 9 and output the respective numbers multiple by 2 for 10 times."

Comment: I meant in the title. That's the most visible part of each question.

Comment: Looks like a good application for a `do..while` loop to me.

Comment: :) I didn want to cause confusion on the question thus kept the title simple, hope the edited title will provide more clarity

Comment: What is the point of asking the user to enter a number? It seems like a silly prompt that is irrelevant to the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things I noticed about your code.

1. Nothing happens if you enter any of the numbers 3,4,5,6,7,8 due to the else if statement checking for below 2 or above 9 instead of anything other than 2 or 9. To resolve this you should use an else instead of an else if as it will catch anything that is not 2 or 9 which is caught in the if statement.
2. You have created a manual infinite loop in your else if, the for loop will keep looping as long as the user enters a number below 2 or above 9 this is dangerous, if the number is not matched then it should reset the user back to a prompt and back to first if statement in theory.

How does the below catch your fancy?

```
let value = prompt("Enter Value between 2 or 9");

let loopAndOutput = function(value){
  if(value == 2 || value == 9){
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      console.log(`${i} times ${value} is:${value * i}`);
    }
  } else {
    let value = prompt("Enter Value between 2 or 9");
    loopAndOutput(value);
  }
}

loopAndOutput(value);
```

Comment: @ChrisWright it looks better; While this isn't StackOverflow and it isn't really imperative, the snippet output isn't the same as that of the OP's code but perhaps you are leaving it as an exercise to the reader to alter it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

### Feedback

#### Logic flaw

I noticed that if I enter a value greater than `2` and less than `9` (e.g. `4`) then the only thing written is that value that I entered. Should that be the case? And what about non-integer numbers - should 2.3 be accepted?

#### Keywords, ES-6 features

Your code uses the keyword `let`, which became standard with the [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Specifications)</sup> specification, as well as [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Specifications) which also became standard with that same specification. That means there are other ecmascript-6 features that could be used to simplify this code like [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill). Also, `const` can be used for any value that doesn't need to be re-assigned, like `value`. That way there is no risk of accidental re-assignment elsewhere in the code.

#### Variable scoping

Because none of your code is wrapped in a function most variables are visible globally. However, some are declared with `let`, like `value` and the `i` within the first `for` loop - those would be visible within any enclosing braces. However other variables are not declared with a keyword like `var`, `const` or `let`, which means those are global variables.

#### Use of `document.write()`

I see this code utilizes `document.write()`. In a larger application, that would likely lead to complications because any existing content would be cleared. For more reasons, see [this top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/1575353) (as well as the others) to [*Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1575353). A better approach might be to have a container in the DOM that can be updated when appropriate.

#### Rewrite

The code below uses `document.getElementById()` to fetch a reference to a DOM element and update its contents once, instead of writing to the document with `document.write`. It also has a `while` loop to ensure the value is either `2` or `9`. That could be re-written as a `for` loop if desired.

`parseInt()` is used to convert the input and indexes to integers, to allow proper arithmetic operations before using those numbers in the strings.

```js
let value = -1;
while (![2, 9].includes(value)) {
  value = parseInt(prompt("Enter Value between 2 or 9"), 10);
}

const outputArray = [value];
for (const index in new Array(10).fill()) {
  const value2 = value + parseInt(index, 10);
  outputArray.push(`${value2} times 2 is:${value2 * 2}`);
}
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = outputArray.join('<br/>');
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Specifications</sub>